# TO_DECIMAL for SAP HANA Conversion from String

Tags: sql, arcgis, hana

I am using an SAP HANA DB/table connection to add a query layer in ArcGIS for Desktop.  The table that I would like to use has longitude and latitude fields stored as string data types.  I would like to write a query for this layer which converts these fields as decimal data types so that I am able to present XY data.

An example of my field values are longitude: `-117.619193` and latitude: `33.453381`

The error that is thrown is

> General error; 319 decimal scale specifier is out of range: 6:(0-3)::S1000

Query:

```
select "JOBID", TO_DECIMAL(LONGITUDE,3,6) AS "LONG_DEC", 
       TO_DECIMAL(LATTITUDE,3,6) AS "LAT_DEC" 
from "_SYS_BIC"."SEU.GD.LM/CA_KT_TICKETSTATUS"
```

When I change the decimal identifiers to 3, my precision will not be as correct; how should this be changed to maintain the precision of 6 decimal places?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to misunderstand the parameters for the [TO_DECIMAL() function](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/ee237775191014924e81b18c73c831/content.htm).

```
TO_DECIMAL (<value> [, <precision>, <scale>])
```

With

```
TO_DECIMAL(LONGITUDE,3,6)
```

you are asking for a 3 digit precision and a 6 digit scale.

I assume what you intended was the opposite setting:

```
select   
        TO_DECIMAL( -117.619193 , 6, 3) AS "LONG_DEC"
      , TO_DECIMAL( 33.453381 , 6, 3) AS "LAT_DEC" 
from  dummy;

LONG_DEC    LAT_DEC
-117.619    33.453
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the usual semantics of longitude / latitude, being values between -180 and 180 / -90 and 90,  and considering that you want to maintain the precision of 6 decimal places (after decimal point), I guess you need the following statement:

```
select "JOBID",  
  TO_DECIMAL(LONGITUDE,9,6) AS "LONG_DEC",
  TO_DECIMAL (LATTITUDE,8,6) AS "LAT_DEC"   
from "_SYS_BIC"."SEU.GD.LM/CA_KT_TICKETSTATUS
```

TO_DECIMAL (LATTITUDE,8,6) woud mean a target decimal type with 8 places, whereof 6 after the decimal point.

Be aware, that values with absolute value >= 1000 for longitude and >=100 for latitude will lead to error. If you want do be less restrictive here and catch wrong values at the application layer you might want to use a higher precision, e.g. to_decimal(LONGITUDE, 12,6).